# iptable rule that works once a month

Tags: iptables

Is it possible to create a rule that works once a month (or every two or three months)? I found an example of a rule that can work several times a week:

*iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 513:65535 -d 202.54.1.20 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m time **--timestart 09:00 --timestop 18:00 --days Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri** -j ACCEPT*

but there is nothing about "once a month"

Comment: In [`man 8 iptables-extensions`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html) I see `--monthdays`. But I also see `--weekdays`, not `--days` you used, so I'm not sure if this applies. Therefore only a comment.

Comment: where did you find that example?